# Tell Windows 10 firewall to stop prompting me to allow apps access after each reboot

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall

For programs such as: Skype, Chrome, ditto. . . .

- The Windows 10 firewall It seems that each time I reboot the PC I have to accept a pop up for Windows Firewall to allow the app access. Each time I reboot, I have to do this again when it prompts.

Is there a way for me to prevent this from occurring so the Windows Firewall knows that I allow these apps access so I can just use them?

**EDIT** screenshot of the alert:
[image]

Comment: i am quite sure it was some sort of anti virus software / maleware spyware removal software that I installed. Resetting all the rules every couple seconds. Now i once had the feeling I was attacked so i installed a bunch, but dont remember which one cause the issue. I got a new computer last december, so i cannot give more input on this i fear

Comment: i upvoted your answer for the effort, I dont think it solves the question though, as the rules are reset each couple seconds

Comment: actually it is not malware that caused that problem on my computer, but the anti malware software I installed.

Comment: Okay, just let me know when you write up the correct answer that answers your question and I'll look it over. Thanks for the chat!

Answer (score 5):

### Allow Apps through Windows Firewall with Command Line

You can setup a Windows Firewall rule with [NETSH](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) to allow a specific application inbound and/or outbound on any profile from an elevated command prompt **run as administrator** with the below syntax or something similar:

Confirm the full explicit paths of the programs you want to allow incoming and outgoing thru the Windows Firewall for all applicable profiles, and set them correctly for each where needed in `program="<value>"` with the value needed there being the full path e.g. `C:\path\path\app.exe`.

---

<sup>*Setting up a Windows Firewall rules to allow an app inbound and outbound will help prevent the prompting of the Windows Firewall you may get each time an app is launched and asked you to allow it.*</sup>

### Allow App Outbound

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Skype Out" dir=out action=allow program="C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Chrome Out" dir=out action=allow program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
```

---

### Allow App Inbound

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Skype In" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Chrome In" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**NETSH**](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)
- [**Top 10: Windows Firewall Netsh Commands**](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/top-10-windows-firewall-netsh-commands)

Answer (score 3):

### Allow Apps thru Windows Firewall with Advanced Security GUI options

You could also go to **wf.msc** and then add a rule to tell the **Windows Firewall** to allow a specific app inbound and/or outbound on all profiles.

> ### Instructions
>
> 1. Press [image] **+**<kbd>**R**</kbd>,
>      type in **wf.msc** and then press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>.
> 2. Click on **Inbound Rules** and then click on **New Rule...** to the
>      right
>
>    [image]
> 3. In the **Rule Type** options window check the **Program** option and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the **Program** options window in the **This program path** field either **browse** find or specify the full explicit path of the
>      exe of the apps file which you want to allow through the **Windows
>      Firewall** and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 5. In the **Actions** options window ensure the **Allow this connection** option is selected and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 6. In the **Profile** options window ensure that all three options of **Domain**, **Public**, and **Private** are selected and then press <kbd>**Next**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 7. In the **Name** field type in a name for the new rule and then press <kbd>**Finish**</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 8. You should now see the new rule you just created. You could then click on the **Outbound Rules** option and follow the same *steps 1 - 8* as
>      listed above for the app you need to allow outbound connections.
>
>    [image]
>
> Just follow these steps for allowing all the incoming and outgoing app rules you need and scale accordingly to prevent Windows Firewall from prompting after each reboot.

Comment: actually still happens on each boot, i did inbound and outbound

Comment: can it be that it does not get saved for some reasons? i cannot see the rules any more when i open wf.msc

Answer (score 0):

To whoever in future it may concern. (about NETSH method in previous
[answer by IT solution](https://superuser.com/a/1120718/669275)
, WIN 7)

If you have app listening for connections and Windows still keeps nagging about program add "edge=yes" parameter for inbound direction.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx?

So complete rule command from example would become:

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Skype In" dir=in action=allow program="C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" **edge=yes** enable=yes profile=domain,private,public

For outbound rule there is no "edge" parameter. After adding in and out rule Windows firewall should stop asking user about permission.

Comment: You should quote and cite all relevant information in your answer itself.  Your answer by itself, should have all relevant information, to answer the question.  This currently is not the case.